# Does @SuppressWarnings work with warnings generated by annotations?

Tags: java, annotations, warnings, suppress-warnings

Assume that I have an annotation that generates a warning.  The annotation is on a method.

e.g.

```
@AnnotationThatGeneratesAWarning
public void doSomething() {
  //stuff
}
```

Can I use `@SuppressWarnings` to suppress it?  Does `@SuppressWarnings` work with warnings generated by annotations, or just on warnings generated by the method itself?

Comment: You should post the actual code, a concrete example of the annotation and the warning that's being reported.

Comment: I've posted a concrete example in my answer below.  The question isn't about a specific instance, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What IDE are you using? What's the code that generates the warning?. A good IDE will generally suggest the String to use in the `@SuppressWarnings`, but it's better to first try to fix the warning, if that's not possible and as a last resource use `@SuppressWarnings`.

**EDIT :**

You can tell that `@SuppressWarnings` won't work with other annotations looking at its [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html). As you can see:

```
@Target(value={TYPE,FIELD,METHOD,PARAMETER,CONSTRUCTOR,LOCAL_VARIABLE})
```

The targets do *not* include `ANNOTATION_TYPE`, meaning that `@SuppressWarnings` can not be applied to other annotations.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse and the warning is coming from a Spring MVC annotation.  Eclipse didn't suggest how to suppress the warning but I was able to fix the code easily enough.  That's not really the point, though - I'll edit my question.

Comment: @CosmicFlame I updated my answer, I believe now it's the answer to your question :)

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the following in Eclipse.  The annotations are from Spring MVC.

```
@SuppressWarnings("all")
@RequestMapping("/{foo}/somepage.do")
public void serveAPage() {

}
```

The `{foo}` in the `@RequestMapping` generates a warning as it's not being assigned to a variable*.  The warning description is "URI template variable "foo" is not defined".

`@SuppressWarnings("all")` should suppress all warnings for the method.  Eclipse still shows a warning, despite this.

As far as I can tell, you can't use `@SuppressWarnings` to suppress warnings caused by an annotation.

*This was the code that originally prompted the question.  Fixing the code so it doesn't cause an exception is trivial and not the point of the question.